# A new tag proposal: word-difference

Tags: discussion

There are many questions out there which want to clarify the difference between two similar words.

- What is the difference between X and Y ...
- Kio estas la diferenco inter X kaj Y ...

Shall we use a dedicated tag for them?

Comment: Would this be covered by the word-choice tag?

Comment: @NeilRoberts according to me, word-choice has a different focus. One want to have the most fitting word for some concept. On the other hand, word-difference is focused to understand the difference between two words. But as I said, it's just my opinion and I want a discussion here.

Comment: I see "word-difference" as an unclear meta-tag of "word-usage", "word-choice" and "word-meaning". I have made/read several "What is the difference between X and Y", and often the reason of the question is different. They can ask for a difference in meaning, but sometimes they already know the meaning and they are asking for a difference of usage. Sometimes they are just asking for a subjective preference (a polling of uzindeco) with a question name that does not sound subjective.

Answer (score 3):

Upvote this if you **don't want** the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Upvote this if you **want** such a (or similar) tag (propose it in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

We already have [word-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) and [word-usage](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage).
If the question is about the different meaning of two words, it can use [word-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning), since it is essentially asking about the meaning two words have. If the question is about how to use two words, it can use [word-usage](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage), since it essentially asking about the usage of two words.

[word-choice](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), basing on its tag wiki has a different meaning. It is for questions asking which word to use, given a list of few words.

Comment: Jes :-) We will always have discussion here wether we want to use a more specific tag for a group of questions instead of some more meta tag. And this is OK. The number of questions grows each day and we get more and more question classes. And I always prefer to have such discussion before I introduce a new question class and edit the existing questions.

Comment: My experience on Stack Exchange taught me that more generic tags are more problematic, not because the tag itself, but because how the tag is used. In the beta phase, we tend to use more tags than needed; when we discover it was a bad idea to use a tag, it becomes hard to remove it. In the site where I am moderator, I wish we never used some tags; it was very hard to remove them when too much questions used them.